# how to tabulate word transition function in discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The state transition table is
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
   && f_a && f_b \\ \hline 
S_0 && S_1 && S_6 \\
S_1 && S_1 && S_4 \\
S_2 && S_3 && S_5 \\
S_3 && S_1 && S_4 \\
S_4 && S_6 && S_5 \\
S_5 && S_6 && S_5 \\
S_6 && S_4 && S_5\\
\end{array}
$$

Question:
Tabulate the word transition function $f_{abaa}$

My answer:

$\begin{align}
f_{abaa} &=f_a(f_a(f_b(f_a(S_0)))) \\
&= f_a(f_a(f_b(S_1(S_0)))) \\
&= f_a(f_a(f_b(S_1))) \\
&= f_a(f_a(S_4)) \\
&= f_a(S_6) \\
&= S_4
\end{align}$

is it correct?

Comment: @Joffan erm,.for example? so is S4 is the correct one?

Comment: hi, can anyone tell my answer is correct or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

is it correct... yes and no.

The question asked for a tabulation, so if I were assessing this I would be delighted to see a table of the various intermediate combinations leading to the final column showing the required combined mapping.

As for the assertion that it evaluates to a single value; in fact it does, but you have not done enough to prove it. I will use your order for function composition, although it may possibly be the other way around - applying the mappings right to left.

The range (image) of $fa, \text{rng}(fa) = \{S1, S3, S4, S6\}$. Then $\text{rng}(fab) = \{S4, S5\}$ (because these are the values generated by $\text{rng}(fa)$ under $fb$ ), $\text{rng}(faba)=\{S6\}$ and $\text{rng}(fabaa)=\{S4\}$.

With the opposite order of composition, the final set consists of $S6$ alone.

Answer (score 0):

The second line of the expansion of $f_{abaa}$ shouldn’t be there; the rest of your calculation of $f_{abaa}(S_0)$ is correct, however.

More important, you haven’t answered the question: it requires you to construct a table showing $f_{abaa}$. That table has the following form:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
&f_{abaa}\\ \hline
S_0&S_4\\
S_1&f_{abaa}(S_1)\\
S_2&f_{abaa}(S_2)\\
S_3&f_{abaa}(S_3)\\
S_4&f_{abaa}(S_4)\\
S_5&f_{abaa}(S_5)\\
S_6&f_{abaa}(S_6)
\end{array}$$

Here I’ve filled in the one value that you’ve actually calculated. Thus, you still need to find $f_{abaa}(S_n)$ for $1\le n\le 6$. As **Joffan**’s answer points out, this doesn’t require actually doing six more calculations like the one that you’ve already done. You need only notice

- that $f_a(S_n)$ is always $S_1,S_3,S_4$, or $S_6$,
- that if $n\in\{1,3,4,6\}$, then $f_b(S_n)$ is $S_4$ or $S_5$,
- that $f_a(S_4)=f_a(S_5)=S_6$, and
- that $f_a(S_6)=S_4$,

so that every entry in the transition table above is $S_4$.